# UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile - produces corrupted image, if file is deleted

Tags: ios, uiimage

Loading image from file directly produces corrupted image if file is deleted, for example downloading image using NSURLSession and loading it to file produced corrupted image.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by loading file contents to NSData, and then creating image using data.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :)